# How to build war with a selected profile in maven from command line

Tags: java, spring, maven

We have a Spring based project that we are using for creating a REST Server. It is maven controlled and has profiles pointing to different servers as and when required. I need a mechanism so that I can build war files on the runtime using command line.

Sample Profile tags

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <properties>
            <run.scheduledjob>YES</run.scheduledjob>
            <logfile.location>/var/lib/tomcat7/logs</logfile.location>
            <imagefile.location>/tmp/tmpImages</imagefile.location>
            <elasticsearch.host>{elastic-sample}</elasticsearch.host>
            <db.username>{username}</db.username>
            <db.url>{url}</db.url>
            <db.password>{password}</db.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <properties>
            <run.scheduledjob>YES</run.scheduledjob>
            <logfile.location>/var/lib/tomcat7/logs</logfile.location>
            <imagefile.location>/tmp/tmpImages</imagefile.location>
            <elasticsearch.host>{elastic-sample}</elasticsearch.host>
            <db.username>{username}</db.username>
            <db.url>{url}</db.url>
            <db.password>{password}</db.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I need to select qa or development at runtime using maven command line switch,
I tried `mvn clean install -Pqa` or `mvn clean install -Pdevelopment` but was not able to evaluate was the profile actually activated.

Can someone help out?

Comment: what do you mean with runtime? maven only controls the build and is not available at runtime of your application. What you Needs are different properties for each stage?

Comment: So what I am doing is trying a CI using Jenkins where I run a maven build but dont want to save 2 differnt poms for that. So was looking for something in maven switch that can build war from the profiles passed in through command line.

Comment: Looks like you do not need to poms, you Need two porperty files, which are included in the profiles

Comment: Yeah Jens I agree with what you are saying but I have already added two different profiles with different properties, all I need is to select them while building the war from command line. There are ways in eclipse in which we can select the profiles I just need a simple command line translation for that.

Comment: You have to put the properties in files like qa.properties and development.properties and put this in the jar bei renaming the file you want to use to config.properties and read this in your applkication